# Writing to file with batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, set

I'm trying to get a batch file to take user input and place it in a file... here is my code so far.

```
set /p input path=Path:
echo %path% >> log.txt
```

when I turn echo off, it's putting a "1" infront of the chevrons like so:

```
echo C:/Example/Path 1>> log.txt
the system can not find the file specified.
```

Please can anyone explain this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SET` statement is wrong. :-) Also, `PATH` is already assigned in the environment (the Windows `PATH`, and altering it may cause problems with running other commands in your batch file.

Try this instead:

```
set /p "Input=Path: " 
echo %Input% >> log.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Certainly - I'll answer the question asked.

Originally, `>somewhere` or any redirection sent the data to the destination specified.

With the changes to the NT version, this was expanded. A digit DIRECTLY preceding a redirector means `logical file number` where 0=STDIN (standard-input) 1=STDOUT (standard output) and 2=STDERR (Standard error.) The others are undefined. This *can* cause problems where the data (typically) to be output ends with a digit, hence the `>filename echo ...` syntax

Consequently, for backward compatibility, (eg) `>nul` is still processed as it always has been, but it's `ECHO`ed in its explict form `1>nul` - sending STDOUT to `nul` to distinguish it from `2>somewhere_else`

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
set /p "MyNewPath=Path: "
>>log.txt echo %MyNewPath%
```